# Solve $(a^2+b)(a+b^2)=(a-b)^3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

> Solve $(a^2+b)(a+b^2)=(a-b)^3$ with $a, b \in\mathbb{Z}$

I get that

$b(a^2b+3a^2+a+2b^2-3ab)=0$

If $b=0$ so $a=k$, $k\in\mathbb{Z}$

I stuck when i would solve if $b\neq 0$

Comment: for $b\neq 0$ there are only 4 cases, $a=8, b=-10$ and $a=b=-1$ and...

Comment: $b=-21, a=9$ ; $b=-6, a=9$